# iphone application

Tags: ios4

How to insert drop down list box in iphone application development?I didn"t find it in library.

Comment: @user530131: Please accept one of the answers as "accepted answers" as it helps out the community of Stackoverflow when you do so, and also adds to your own rating.

Answer (score 2):

In iPhone Programming the "drop down list box" is called a "Picker View"

---

Note:

Add the following tags: iphone , objective-c , xcode

That will enable more people to find your post.